# Plot function with else if statement in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, plot

trying to plot the following function over the interval [-1,1] but am getting error code:

```
"Warning messages:
1: In if (g < a) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (g >= a & g <= b) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

unifCDF<-function(g) {
  if (g< a) {
    0
  }
  else if (g>=a & g<=b) {
    (g-a)/(b-a)
  }
  else if (g>b) {
    1
  }
}
```

I know the function itself works since unifCDF() works for all values I tested.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where are `a` and `b` defined, and what type are you passing into the `unifCDF()` function?

Comment: a = -1 b = 1, and unifCDF is a function of g

Comment: `if` is for one value compared to another. `if(2 > 1) print("yes")` - not for comparing to multiple values. E.g. `if(2 > c(1,2,3)) print("yes")` warns and gives a result for only the first comparison.

Comment: I used plot.function(unifCDF,from=a,to=b)

Comment: That doesn't completely answer my question, but do you see that it makes no sense to compare a vector to a single value, and then to assert a single inequality on that comparison?  If you compare the vector `[1,2,3,4,5]` against `a = -1`, then what should be the result?  What is your logic here?

Comment: I'm not trying to compare vectors just a variable.  Do I have it defined solely as a vector?  I thought if I wrote it using the function command it would work

Comment: "*the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*" - that's the same error I get when trying to compare vectors instead of single values.

Comment: Let's take this one step at a time.  You pass in vector `g`, you compare each elements in `g` against `a`.  What logical output do you want from that?  If you want a single number, then how do you get from a vector to that single number?

Comment: I want it to perform the defined function for each element passed into it.  So if you pass in g=0 it would go to the second set of inequalities and return .5

Comment: So if the intervals between each g become infinitely small, we would just get a line from 0 to 1 over the y and -1 to 1 over g

Comment: I somehow got it to plot a line if I just added return(0) instead of 0 and return(1) instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function works on single values:

```
> unifCDF(.5)
[1] 0.75
```

but not on vectors:

```
> unifCDF(c(0.2,.3))
[1] 0.60 0.65
Warning messages:
1: In if (g < a) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (g >= a & g <= b) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and plot.function needs functions to work on vectors. The lazy way is to just `Vectorize` your function:

```
> unifCDF=Vectorize(unifCDF)
> unifCDF(c(0.2,.3))
[1] 0.60 0.65
> plot.function(unifCDF,-1,1)
```

which then works.

The right way is to code it so that it handles vector arguments naturally.

```
unifCDF = function(g){
   res = (g-a)/(b-a)
   res[g<a]=0
   res[g>b]=1
   res
}
```

in this code, `res` is always a vector of the same length as `g`. The first line computes the slopey bit for all values of `g`, and then the next two lines set the relevant bits outside the (a,b) limits to 0 and 1.

Note that having global variables, like `a` and `b` are generally a bad thing.